# How do I connect to Binance using the Shrimpy Universal Crypto Exchange APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, get

I have recently begun exploring the [Shrimpy Developer APIs](https://developers.shrimpy.io) for their Universal Crypto Exchange APIs. I was reading through the docs [here](https://developers.shrimpy.io/docs/), but I was having trouble understanding how you actually connect to Binance (or any other exchange like Bittrex, KuCoin, Coinbase, Kraken, etc). It looks like you need to first create a user key, and then connect using that key. Would someone be able to provide some direction for this issue?

This section details how to create a user:

```
This endpoint creates a new user. New users are disabled by default.

See also: Enabling a User, User.

HTTP Request
POST https://dev-api.shrimpy.io/v1/users

Response
Field   Type    Description
id  UUID    The id of the newly created user. This id is used in future requests for this user.
```

I assume this is what I need to use to create the user. Then I can use this call to connect the exchange account:

```
Create API Keys
Request

POST https://dev-api.shrimpy.io/v1/users/701e0d16-1e9e-42c9-b6a1-4cada1f395b8/keys
Response:

{
    "publicKey": "51ac18b7d208f59b3c88acbb1ecefe6ba6be6ea4edc07e7a2450307ddc27ab80",
    "privateKey": "85c977ef4070f1deee70192ba7fd5a6caf534f891e4918cfffec11cd6b625e77db4f80347cb436bcaa8882231bacb02f0798a696f101fdd1ef268d66fc63c213"
}
This endpoint will create new User API keys for a particular user. By default new User API Keys have no permissions. User API Keys have a rate limit of 60 requests per minute.

See also: Set API Key Permissions, Delete API Keys.

HTTP Request
POST https://dev-api.shrimpy.io/v1/users/<userId>/keys

URL Parameters
Parameter   Type    Description
userId  UUID    The id of the user for which to create api keys.
Response
Field   Type    Description
publicKey   string  The public key of the newly created User API Key.
privateKey  string  The private key of the newly created User API Key.
```

I would appreciate any insights into this matter!